# I want to test iphone app on my windows laptop

Tags: iphone

I want to test an iPhone app on my Windows laptop.

Is there any tool / simulator?

How can I install the build on that simulator?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are no known iPhone emulators for windows on which you can test iPhone applications.

The only alternative I can think of is installing Mac OS X in a virtualbox virtual machine and run XCode and the iOS emulator in an virtual machine. Although this might be a legal issue, since you are not allowed to virtualize Mac OS X under Windows. Never the less see this blog explaining how to install it in a VM: http://www.macbreaker.com/2015/01/virtualbox-yosemite-zone.html

If you want todo real iPhone development and testing cheaply your best bet is to buy a second hand Mac Mini.

Answer (score 0):

Although [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) is for developing iPhone apps, you can still use it to simulate an iPhone and use it on Windows.

This has been asked on StackOverflow: [iPhone Development on Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839875/iphone-app-development-on-eclipse-ide)

Comment: I don't have iPhone. I want to test app build on windows laptop with the help of simulator.Which simulator i can use and how to install build on that simulator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simulator: iPadian https://ipadian.net/

Comment: Do you have experience with iPadian? From their website i read: "iOS Looks and Feel" which makes me think it is not the actual thing and things that work in iPadian might not work in iOS and the other way around.

Comment: How can i install build to test in iPadian

Answer (score 0):

You can install iPhone apps in windows laptop.But this is not correct environment for iPhone apps. You can miss different GUI bugs.
Must test apps in real device.

You can test apps in Cloud like ( http://xamarin.com/test-cloud )